# Another monitor detected even if there isn't one plugged in 

Tags: 11.04, monitor

It seems that Ubuntu 11.04 (and Lubuntu, and probably others too) seem to detect a DVI monitor even if I don't have anything other than this VGA monitor plugged in. It never happened in earlier version of Ubuntu.

I'm not using a laptop though, I'm using a desktop with an Intel Atom. Maybe thats why it's detecting (or trying to detect) another "monitor"

Any way how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can make X ignore certain (phantom) ports by adding entries like this to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI1"
    Option     "Ignore"    "True"
EndSection
```

In this case the HDMI1 port gets ignored. To find out which ports you might want to ignore, you can run

```
xrandr -q
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the non existing monitor via Dash->Monitors. You can also consider reporting a bug about this on bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu.